# How to implement SEO in Bolt CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

I need to update mata title, description and keyword for each page.But in bolt dashboard there is no option for that.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an extesnion for SEO that allows you to edit the meta tags, the title and the index rules: https://market.bolt.cm/view/bobdenotter/seo

The SEO extension also lets you edit OG tags.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt even install properly. 
Is there a way to just enter it in the twig files directly and forget about the extension. Thanks

Comment: After you install the extension, you also need to add a SEO field to the contenttypes where you want to use the SEO extension, and the twig tags to your page templates. ( see https://bobdenotter.github.io/seo/ for the documentation )

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that fields in configuration and templates. 
Edit your content types for each item type, then use that field into your template.

Example:

Code in your contenttypes file:

```
page:
    name: Page 
    singular_name: Page Item 
    fields:
        title:
            type: text
            class: large
        slug:
            type: slug
            uses: title
```

Template sample:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
```

More info in their documentation about contenttypes: https://docs.bolt.cm/3.6/contenttypes/intro